# Trying to Implement simple API in Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-models

I am very new to Django and trying to implement small API for social media website where I can monitor if post has been liked and number of likes and later fetch API using JavaScript so I can like without refreshing the page using put method. Problem is that I largely failed because of lack of proper knowledge. I could not get the API working in the first place.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class New_Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    New_Post =  models.CharField(null=True, max_length=300)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.New_Post}"

class Likes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    like = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    New_Post =  models.ForeignKey(New_Post, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def serialize(self):
        return {
        "id": self.id,
        "post": self.New_Post,
        "user": self.user,
        "like": self.like
    }
```

views.py fragment

```
def likes(request):
    like = Likes.objects.all()
    return JsonResponse(like.serialize())
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("Post", views.likes, name="likes"),
]
```

When I try to access Post url I expect json response to be shown on mostly blank page. Should it be like that? How can I get my API working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serialize method handles one Like object while like is an a list of likes, which doesn't have such a function

One technique is to loop on the objs inside

```
def likes(request):
    likes = [l.serialize() for l in Likes.objects.all()]
    return JsonResponse(likes,safe=False)
```

safe is False as JSONResponse wants an object by default.

Comment: Your answer mostly works for me, but it gives me error :"Object of type New_Post is not JSON serializable". I found out that error is because of it being a foreignkey because when I remove foreignkeys from serialize it displays json response properly. How can I include foreginkeys in Json response? Maybe another loop?

Comment: You should take New_Post object and serialize it too, just as you serialized Likes model.

Comment: I got it working. I will check this answer. Thanks Mohamed!